# Tensorflow tutorial code not showing image

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm learning about computer vision and I'm trying to get this code working, it doesn't show any error but it doesn't display any image.
I've found that this may be solved by changing plt.show() to plt.show(block=false) and adding plt.pause(5) but it doesn't work.
I'm new into python but I've displayed images before but can't figure out what is that I'm doing wrong.

If someone could give me a clue I would be very appreciated.

The code can be found here:
https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/plot_object_detection_saved_model.html

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')   # Suppress Matplotlib warnings

def load_image_into_numpy_array(path):
   Load an image from file into a numpy array.

    Puts image into numpy array to feed into tensorflow graph.
    Note that by convention we put it into a numpy array with shape
    (height, width, channels), where channels=3 for RGB.

    Args:
      path: the file path to the image

    Returns:
      uint8 numpy array with shape (img_height, img_width, 3)
    
    return np.array(Image.open(path))


for image_path in IMAGE_PATHS:

    print('Running inference for {}... '.format(image_path), end='')

    image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image_path)

    # Things to try:
    # Flip horizontally
    # image_np = np.fliplr(image_np).copy()

    # Convert image to grayscale
    # image_np = np.tile(
    #     np.mean(image_np, 2, keepdims=True), (1, 1, 3)).astype(np.uint8)

    # The input needs to be a tensor, convert it using `tf.convert_to_tensor`.
    input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_np)
    # The model expects a batch of images, so add an axis with `tf.newaxis`.
    input_tensor = input_tensor[tf.newaxis, ...]

    # input_tensor = np.expand_dims(image_np, 0)
    detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)

    # All outputs are batches tensors.
    # Convert to numpy arrays, and take index [0] to remove the batch dimension.
    # We're only interested in the first num_detections.
    num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
    detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
                   for key, value in detections.items()}
    detections['num_detections'] = num_detections

    # detection_classes should be ints.
    detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

    image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

    viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np_with_detections,
          detections['detection_boxes'],
          detections['detection_classes'],
          detections['detection_scores'],
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          max_boxes_to_draw=200,
          min_score_thresh=.30,
          agnostic_mode=False)

    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(image_np_with_detections)
    print('Done')
plt.show()

# sphinx_gallery_thumbnail_number = 2
```

Comment: What shell do you use? Is it Jupyter notebook, Google Colab, PyCharm, etc?

Comment: I'm using Anaconda3 and Python 3.8. Thank you!

Comment: Please post the OS and path to your Tensor Object Detection here.

Answer (score 1):

The backend for matplotlib gets overridden to Agg in `visualization_utils` upon importing. So it will only display images on jupyter-notebooks. You need to set it back to something else if you are not using a notebook.

Add the below code just after you import viz_utils (should be line: `from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils`):

```
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

or look up another backend